# How to simplify the code below by using cycles?

Tags: expl3, foreach, xparse, renewcommand

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand[3]{\mycounter}{a=#1, b=#2, c=#3}

\begin{document}
\mycounter{1}{2}{3}
\mycounter{4}{5}{6}
Too much… and the last line is
\mycounter{28}{29}{30}
\end{document}
```

I want to simplify the 10 lines with a command: `\command{1}{30}`, and if I input `\command{1}{29}`, then the last line of the command will output as `\mycounter{28}{29}{29}`; if I input `\command{1}{28}`, then the last line of the command will output as `\mycounter{28}{28}{28}`. How can I achieve this command?

Comment: Or `pgfkeys`. Or any other package which provides a loop with syntax you like.

Comment: It's not clear what is constant and what is variable. Are the arguments always the first *n* natural numbers? Are there always 10 lines to be simplified? If so, you only need one argument, which will always be `28` or `29` or `30`. But why would you want a loop to do that?

Comment: Actually, I’m developing a template to input the beamers on a letter paper. I designed to input 3 slides on the left side of a paper, and I can use the empty area on the right side to write notes on my iPad. For example, the teacher gives me a Beamer with 28 pages, then I need 10 pages of note to input the Beamer, and the command is the code I referred above. Each command has 3 variables that refer three pages of the Beamer and create a note page.

Comment: So I think if I write 10 times of the command to create 10 pages, it’s so awful, and I want to simplify the 10 commands with only one command, which has only 2 variables, one is the first page number of the Beamer and the other one is the last page of the Beamer that I want to input.

Comment: Do you have the source for the Beamer or PDF or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\loop` cycle defined in plain TeX too. You don't need to load any more LaTeX packages and the code works in plain TeX too.

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\mycounter#1#2#3{a=#1, b=#2, c=#3 \par}
\def\command#1#2{%
   \def\maxnum{#2}\tmpnum=1 
   \loop
      \unless\ifnum\tmpnum>#2 \mycounter{\valnum0}{\valnum1}{\valnum2}
      \advance\tmpnum by3
   \repeat
}
\def\valnum#1{%
   \ifnum\maxnum>\numexpr\tmpnum+#1\relax 
      \the\numexpr\tmpnum+#1\relax \else \maxnum\fi
}

\command{1}{29}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the best method in my view! Elegant! It’s so elegant!

Answer (score 3):

`multido` is almost designed for what your question asks for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\printnextthree[1]{#1, \the\numexpr#1+1\relax, \the\numexpr#1+2\relax \par}

\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\multido{\i=1+3}{9}{\printnextthree{\i}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

But for your [actual problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699639/how-to-simplify-the-code-below-by-using-cycles#comment1738846_699639), why reinvent the wheel? Just use `pdfpages`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[offset=-2in 0in,nup=1x3,pages=-]{testpdf.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The specification of `nup=1x3` puts one column of 3 slides on each page, `pages=-` tells it to include all pages, and `offset=-2in 0in` tells it to shift each included slide 2 inches to the left (otherwise it would be horizontally centered).

Sample output when run against one set of my old slides:

[image]

Comment: OK, the problem has been solved. Thank you very much! For the reason I didn’t use pdfpages, I want to input every 3 pages of a Beamer on a letter page. However, pdfpages package can only input PDF Documents as single pages, it couldn’t input multiple pages float on a note page.

Comment: @Axia: try the code I showed you. The `nup` option allows you to put multiple PDF pages on one page. The code I included specifically puts 3 PDF slides onto the same page, pushed to the left, with space left over on the right for notes.